# Wolfram Mathematica неправильно считает ряд

Tags: функции, ряды, mathematica, точность

*Функция f (x) приближенно может быть задана рядом r(x,n). Написать программу в Wolfram Mathematica, которая дает возможность найти значение n при котором |f(x) - r(x,n)| <= Epselon . Для построения ряда r(x,n) использовать функцию Series[f,{x, x0, n}].*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
f[x_] := Csc[6*x - 7]
x0 = 5;
eps = 10^-10;
n = 0;
While[Abs[f[x0] - Series[f[x], {x, x0, n}]] > eps, n++]
Print["Результат = ", n]
```

Но почему-то в результате всегда n = 0 при любых x0 , что я сделал неправильно?